# Inserting the Line Breaks in the XML data dynamically

Tags: xml, w3c

```
"<log date=\"" + date +
 "\" trnType=\"" +
 "\" accountType=\"" + XMLIllegalCharacterEncoder.encodedString(accountType) +
 "\" ***accountId=\"" + accountBSB + "\r\n" + accountId*** +
"\" groupingID=\"" + groupingId +
"\"/>"
```

I am trying to insert an Line Break in the XML data which I am creating dynamically. 
I have tried few options, but nothing worked to insert the line break inside the XML data

In the Below piece of Code,

```
 "\" ***accountId=\"" + accountBSB + "\r\n" + accountId*** +
```

Trying to insert an Break between accountBSB  and accountId

can any one help me the solutions with this

Comment: What technology are you using to create it? You should consider using a CDATA section

Comment: Java technology to create the XMl data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\r\n`, try  `&#10;`.

However, I would recommend against constructing XML using cut-n-paste techniques. Use a proper tool like JDOM or DOM4J (if you are using java)

UPDATE:

According to the XML specification, an attribute value must be "normalized" before it is passed to the application (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize). Briefly, the normalization process replaces `\r\n` sequneces with a single white space character. Any character reference, such as `&#10;` is preserved. So, in your case, if you want an application consuming your XML to actually see the line break, you must use a character reference instead of literal carriage return and line feed.

Comment: <log date="23/08/2011 17:37" trnType="Deposit" accountType="FM" accountId="015141&#10;3134 86793" accountName="BAULCH G A &amp;" groupingID=""/> I used your suggestion, when I generate the XML file, "&#10;" is coming in the XML data only ,,  Please suggest